# Creating link areas on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, imagemap

I want to create an image with a link map. The map will contain many areas which have to change very often. Instead of recreating the areas every few seconds I would like to only create them when the user really clicks on the image.

I hoped this would be possible by creating the areas once a `mousedown` event is fired - but this does not seem to work (the click on the new created area is not processed).

My javascript code so far ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFVVh/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#overlayDiv').mousedown(function () {
        $('#image').click(function () {
            $('#linkmap').children().remove();
            $(document.createElement('area'))
                .attr("shape", "rect")
                .attr("onclick", "alert('click');")
                .attr("coords", "0,0, 400,400")
                .appendTo('#linkmap');
        });
    });
});
```

**A "workflow" of what should happen**

1. Click on the image
2. All existing areas are deleted
3. The area are recreated
4. The click is processed on the **new** area

Comment: Please, remove that inline attribute handler and use `.click(function(e){alert(e.type);})` instead

Comment: Seems you rather want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gFVVh/2/) (though it doesn't work as well)

Comment: You're right, it does not work. I'll add a "workflow" to my question

Comment: What do you mean by "change very often"? How often, and why? Why do you want to use explicit `<area>`s, might dynamic lookup of click coordinates in your data be a better solution?

Comment: I am about to create a dynamic map. The user should be able to click on specified areas in order to create buildings. These buildings should be clickable as well. Additionally, the map should be moveable. I thought this would be possible by using some javascript, areas and some images, but especially when the map is moved, the reposition of the areas is to heavy for some browsers/computers. I already tried a dynamic lookup, but didn't know how to calculate the areas (they are shapes, no simple rects). But maybe I settled on the wrong horse and another language than javascript would be better?

Comment: Nah, JS should be fine. How do you move the map? If that is a too heavy task, you should rather ask a question on how to improve the move code.

Comment: All my images are positioned relative to an surrounding div. If the user moves the map, actually only the position of this div is changed. And moving the map isn't really to heavy, only recreating the areas after finishing the moving is too slow.

Comment: Why do you need to recreate the areas at all, aren't they relative to the images (which don't change, but only move)?

Comment: Sounds like a valid point, this will help me to reduce the workload. But my map should be infinitive wide, so I'm unable to create all the areas right at the beginning. Instead, I have to create them once they appear to the user. Cause my map will show ~100 fields that's still to heavy for the browser. Especially if the user moves the map very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working for you, because you don't have a name attribute in your map tag.

Check out the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gFVVh/1/

```
<img src="https://www.google.de/logos/2013/henry_van_de_veldes_100th_birthday-1402005-hp.jpg" usemap="#linkmap" id="image" />
<map id="linkmap" name="linkmap"></map>
```

Comment: "Clicked" does not appear on the first click. Afterwards, the area already exists, and does not seem to become deleted, so the popup appears.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because that's not how you have it programmed. The mousedown is creating the click event on the image, which in turn, creates the area. So, the way it reads is: "after user does a mousedown on 'overlayDiv', create the click event on 'image', which removes the children of the 'linkmap', then create a new area inside of the 'linkmap', which has the click event 'alert(click)'". If you want to send a 'click' to something, use $(element).click() after you've defined the onClick event.